# What's the equivalent of MySQL's \G for Firebird database?

Tags: firebird

I can use `\G` with MySQL to get select query output in a more readable format. Is there any similar way to display select query output in a more readable way in Firebird?

Comment: what does "more readable" mean for you? `select 'John went to ' || t.Place || ' shop and bought ' || t.Qty || ' pieces of ' || t.SKU from Purchases T`

Comment: What does `\G` do? What result do you expect? What sort of readability are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the behaviour of `\G` correcty, the closest equivalent would be `SET LIST ON` in ISQL. Be aware, this is a ISQL-only command.

See the Firebird ISQL manual on [`SET LIST`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-list):

> ```
> SQL> set list off;
>
> SQL> select emp_no, first_name, last_name, salary
> CON> from employee;
>
>  EMP_NO FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME                           SALARY 
> ======= =============== ==================== ===================== 
>       2 Robert          Nelson                           105900.00 
>       4 Bruce           Young                             97500.00 
>       5 Kim             Lambert                          102750.00 
>       8 Leslie          Johnson                           64635.00
> ...
>
>
> SQL> set list on;
>
> SQL> select emp_no, first_name, last_name, salary
> CON> from employee;
>
> EMP_NO                          2
> FIRST_NAME                      Robert
> LAST_NAME                       Nelson
> SALARY                          105900.00
>
> EMP_NO                          4
> FIRST_NAME                      Bruce
> LAST_NAME                       Young
> SALARY                          97500.00
> ...
> ```

Contrary to MySQL this is a separate command that changes the setting for the remainder of the session. It is not a statement terminator like `\G` that only influences the query being executed.